# SQL Server's "sp_executesql" is not recognizing parameters

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have the following code:

```
create procedure my_sp_name_here
    @param1 int,
    @param2 nvarchar(128)
as
begin
    ...<sql here>...;
end

declare @paramDef nvarchar(500) = N'@param1 int, @param2 nvarchar(128)';
execute sp_executesql my_sp_name_here, @paramDef, @param1=1, @param2=N'p2';
```

I keep getting an error:

> Procedure or function 'my_sp_name_here' expects parameter @param1,
>   which was not supplied.

I have tried several different configurations and searched, but I haven't found an answer.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your code is strange.  You are calling the same procedure recursively?  Does the outer call have the right parameters?

Comment: Why would you call a procedure with sp_executesql? Can't you just call it directly?

Comment: Double execution problem: use exec or sp_executesql, not both.

Comment: Gordon Linoff - The example was intended to indicate that the procedure was created, then it was called from an outside scope.  I was just trying to show the method signature.  Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In T-SQL, [`exec`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188332.aspx) is a built-in function that can run a SQL statement or call pretty much any type of function or procedure.  It does not accept parameters for a SQL statement, only for a stored procedure.

The stored procedure [`sp_executesql`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx) does support SQL statements with parameters.  The first argument to `sp_executesql` is a SQL statement.  But you're using a stored procedure name as the first argument:

```
execute sp_executesql my_sp_name_here, @paramDef, @param1=1, @param2=N'p2';
```

That's not ok!  To call a stored procedure using `sp_executesql`, you could:

```
exec sp_executesql 
    N'exec my_sp_name_here @param1, @param2', 
    N'@param1 int, @param2 nvarchar(128)',
    @param1 = 42,
    @param2 = 'Answer to The Ultimate Question of Life, the Universe, and Everything';
```

But it's much easier to call a stored procedure using `exec`:

```
exec my_sp_name_here 42, '6*7';
```

You don't have have to supply the parameter names to `exec`, it will accept them in order.

Answer (score 2):

write

```
exec my_sp_name_here @param1=1, @param2=N'p2';
```

instead of

```
execute sp_executesql my_sp_name_here, @paramDef, @param1=1, @param2=N'p2';
```